# Godot vscode doesnt open

Tags: visual-studio-code, godot

I get this error in the Godot console when i try to load c# code in Visual studio code from the Godot Game Engine.

```
platform/windows/os_windows.cpp:2898 - Condition "ret == 0" is true. Returned: ERR_CANT_FORK
 editor/plugins/script_editor_plugin.cpp:2119 - Couldn't open external text editor, using internal
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Did you download the current version?
there are two versions of Godot,
one is the the normal version and another one also supports c#

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the path to your VS Code exe is wrong. Plese go to "Editor" -> "Editor Settings" and then to "Mono" -> "Editor" (all the way at the bottom). Visual Studio Code should be selected there.

If you don't see the "Mono" category, then you're using the non-mono version of Godot which doesn't support C#.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the first few words "platform/windows/os_windows" and the fact that its running as a plugin issue, this is most likely one of two things. It's either a windows error, or what you're code is trying to do is not possible on the godot platform.
Hope this helps!